# Which analytical techniques could you use to research relationships between 2 proteins?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, sequence-analysis, assay-development

Two of the proteins I am researching are known to interact. However, I would like to know if they interact with other proteins as well, and possibly form a pathway. Which analytical technique(s) I should use to determine this if I did all *in silico* analysis already? Any suggestion is welcome.

I am using a nematode *C. elegans* in my research, and RNAi is not an option, as I have already performed it.

Comment: This question is far too broad. From the [help/dont-ask]: *`Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.`* The field of protein-protein interactions is quite wide, and there are numerous techniques to consider. This is not the place to list all of them.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of methods to use. Here is a overview and background of some common methods as written by ThermoFisher:

https://www.thermofisher.com/se/en/home/life-science/protein-biology/protein-biology-learning-center/protein-biology-resource-library/pierce-protein-methods/overview-protein-protein-interaction-analysis.html

There is also phage display if you want to find binding partners, which is a very interesting method to narrow down binding partners from an entire interactome. It simple to set up in a lab and you can perform it all in a 96-well plate using ELISA and several rounds of phage selection. And of course there are also e.g. yeast-2-hybrid (Y2H) or co-immunoprecipitation (Co-IP).